# Let $X=\{f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}\}$. Define $f\oplus g=h$ by $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$. (i) Show $(X, \oplus)$ is a group. (ii) Show $\{f\in X\mid f(0)=0\}\le X$.

Tags: group-theory, functions

> Let $X= \{f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} \}$. Define an operation $\oplus$ such that $f \oplus g = h$, where $h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $+$ is the regular addition from real numbers.
> (i) Show that $(X, \oplus)$ is a group.
> (ii) Show that $Y = \{f \in X \mid f(0)=0\} \subset X$  is a subgroup.

So I know the definitions for (i) we need to show the associative property, existence of the identity and the inverse element. For (ii) we need to show that $Y \ne \emptyset$, that it's closed under  the group operation and closed under inverse.

I haven't done these problems with functions and I'm not sure where to start here. How can I even use $f\oplus g = h$ for the associative property? $g \oplus f=h?$ This would lead me to $f(x)+g(x)=g(x)+f(x)$?

Comment: the definition of the operation is pointwise addition, so use that definition, and all the good properties of the usual additional operation in $\mathbb{R}$. For example, yes, $f\oplus g = g\oplus f$ since $f(x)+g(x)=g(x)+f(x)$  for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ (since $f(x)$, $g(x)$ are real numbers). So you just need to check if each of the properties holds pointwise, for arbitrary $x\in \mathbb{R}$ though.

Comment: You speak associativity and the equation your wrote looks like commutativity. Revisiting the definitions would be a good start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **closure**, we have, for any $f,g\in X$, $$(f\oplus g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$. Hence $f\oplus g\in X$, since $f(x), g(x)\in \Bbb R$.

**Associativity** of $\oplus$ follows from that of $+$: for any $f,g,h\in X, x\in \Bbb R$, we have

$$\begin{align}
(f\oplus (g\oplus h))(x)&=f(x)+(g\oplus h)(x)\\
&=f(x)+(g(x)+h(x))\\
&=(f(x)+g(x))+h(x)\\
&=(f\oplus g)(x)+h(x)\\
&=((f\oplus g)\oplus h)(x),
\end{align}$$ so $f\oplus (g\oplus h)=(f\oplus g)\oplus h$.

The **identity** is the zero function $0_X:X\to X$ given by $x\mapsto 0$. Indeed, for any $f\in X$, $x\in \Bbb R$, we have

$$\begin{align}
(f\oplus 0_X)(x)&=f(x)+0_X(x)\\
&=f(x)+0\\
&=f(x),
\end{align}$$ so $f\oplus 0_X=f$, and, similarly, $0_X\oplus f=f$.

The **inverse** of an arbitrary $f\in X$ is $(-f):\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ given by $x\mapsto -f(x)$. To verify:

$$\begin{align}
(f\oplus (-f))(x)&=f(x)+(-f)(x)\\
&=f(x)-f(x)\\
&=0_{\Bbb R}\\
&=0_X(x),
\end{align}$$ so $f\oplus(-f)=0_X$, and, dually, $(-f)\oplus f=0_X$.

Hence $(X,\oplus)$ is a group.

---

To show $(Y,\oplus)\le (X, \oplus)$, I will use the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test#:%7E:text=In%20abstract%20algebra%2C%20the%20one,is%20also%20in%20the%20subset.).

We are given that $Y\subset X$. (It is, nonetheless, easy to show; just examine the definition of $Y$.)

Since $0_X(x)=0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$, we have, in particular, that $0_X(0)=0$. Thus $0_X\in Y\neq \varnothing$.

Let $f,g\in Y$. Then $f,g\in X$ such that $f(0)=g(0)=0$, so

$$\begin{align}
(f\oplus (-g))(0)&=f(0)+(-g)(0)\\
&=0-g(0)\\
&=0-0\\
&=0,
\end{align}$$ so $f\oplus (-g)\in Y$ as closure implies $f\oplus (-g)\in X$.

Hence $(Y,\oplus)\le(X,\oplus).$

Comment: Why the downvote?